# chanding contents of spinners run-time (android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a form with  2 spinners, I want the content of the second spinner to be determined by the value of the first spinner. This would entail a runtime determination of a spinners content whereas I am used to declaring the spinner contents using array adapters.
How do I set the adapter for spinner 2 only after user has chosen value for spinner 1???

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the contents of the second Spinner (an array, a DB, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, you can have a data source array:
Initialize with empty, and set this array to adapter data source.

on Selection of first spinner, reset the data source array according to new selection and invoke notifyDataSetChanged() method.